# Почему русские символы занимают два байта в utf-8, если они входят в диапазон от 128 до 255?

Tags: php

А при индексации русской строки символы занимают 16 бит, хотя в расширенной таблице ascii они вполне помещаются в 8 бит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому, что они не входят в диапазон от 128 до 256 в UFT8.

Они входят в этот диапазон в однобайтовых кодировках типа CP1251 или CP866.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Для символов Юникода с номерами от U+0000 до U+007F (занимающими один байт c нулём в старшем бите) кодировка UTF-8 полностью соответствует 7-битной кодировке US-ASCII.

```
Диапазон номеров символов   Требуемое количество октетов
00000000-0000007F            1
00000080-000007FF            2   << Кириллица тут
00000800-0000FFFF            3
00010000-0010FFFF            4
```

Comment: В ASCII и UTF-8 совпадают только первые 128 символов? А для чего это сделано, ведь 8 бит хватает.

Comment: @Мирон 8 бит хватает, но как бы вы тогда отличили например греческий алфавит от русского ? А utf-8 универсальный стандарт, подходящий для всего мира

Comment: 8 бит хватает только на какую-то одну локаль (если она не китайская например). Как вы собираетесь определять, что у вас лежит в этом диапазоне, кириллица, греческий алфавит, немецкие умляюты или египетские иероглифы?